# Display the result of date time picker

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display just the time, like `10:10 AM` in my button.

I set my date time picker mode to time and I tried to use this code:

```
let jam = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(DatePicker.date, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle)
        btnJam.setTitle(jam, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: So, what did your code do? How did it differ from what you wanted?

Comment: I doesn't understand your question. your code is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:-

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePickerView.date)
buttonStartDate.setTitle(strDate, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```